# The most efficient way to handle one to many relationship in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a one-to-many relationship - A user has many todos. I want to be able to perform the following:

- Give me a specific user **without** the todos
- Give me the todos belongs to a specific user
- Give me a single todo by id
- Add, update, and delete todo

I can tackle it in three ways:

### Embedding the todos inside the user document

```
 import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

 const userSchema = model('User', new Schema({
   name:  String,
   todos: [{ title: String, id: String }],
 }));
```

### Use Todo Ref

import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

```
 const userSchema = model('User', new Schema({
   name:  String,
   todos: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Todo"
  }],
 }));

 const todoSchema = model('Todo', new Schema({
   name:  String
 }));
```

### Use Todo Id

```
 import { Schema, model, ObjectId } from 'mongoose';

 const userSchema = model('User', new Schema({
   name:  String
 }));

 const todoSchema = model('Todo', new Schema({
   name:  String,
   userId: ObjectId
 }));
```

What will be the most efficient way to handle this scenario in MongoDB? Adding an index on the `userId` property in the last solution will make the query faster?

Comment: Todos are small set of small sized data, I think. So, you can embed the todos within the user document, as an array of nested documenst.. For your queries, you can have an index on the userid, an index on user name and an index on the array field 'todo.id' (indexes on array fields are called as Multikey Indexes) - for efficient querying.

Comment: avoid DBRef.  Straight from the MongoDB documents - "Unless you have a compelling reason to use DBRefs, use manual references instead."  - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/database-references/

Comment: Unless you have more than 200 elements, embedding data to avoid a lookup will always be faster in MongoDB